# How do I get a variable to print a string

Tags: c++

My question is if there was a way to get an integer variable and then print a specific word when it is set.

What I mean is if someone inputs a value of `1` that is then assigned to variable `int fCur`, is there a way to print a word (for example `Germany`) instead of the value `1` ?

`cout << "You selected "<< fCur << endl;`

I want it to print

> "You selected Germany"

not

> "You selected 1"

I appologize if this is poorly worded this is my first time using this site

Comment: You can use `string` in C++ for this purpose. `string str; if(fCur==1)str="Germany";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have each country indexed as follows:

1. Germany
2. India
3. Korea

you can simply use this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string countries[] = {"Germany", "India", "Korea"};
    int country_number;
    std::cin >> country_number; // invalid input is not being checked

    // array indexing starts from 0
    std::cout << "You selected " << countries[country_number - 1] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What for is the switch?

Comment: What do you mean by 'optional' on break statement? Removing them would be atrociously wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using an enum to represent the options, and to use if statements that will set the string value:

```
int main()
{
    enum Country {GERMANY = 1, SPAIN = 2, ITALY = 3};
    cout << "Enter an option: ";
    int fCur{};
    cin >> fCur;

    string str;
    if (fCur == GERMANY)
        str = "Germany";
    else if (fCur == SPAIN)
        str = "Spain";
    else if (fCur == ITALY)
        str = "Italy";
    else
    ;// Handle error


    cout << "You selected " << str << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I guess it you want to create a menu for selecting options something like -

> 1. Germany
> 2. US
> 3. Spain
> 4. China
>      etc

If it is only integer 1 that is assigned to Germany then an if condition is enough else to display based on the selection from a menu use `switch`

```
int n;
cin >> n;
switch(n) {
     case 1: {
                  cout << "Germany" << endl;
                  break;
             }
     case 2: {
                  cout << "US" << endl;
                  break;
             }
     case 3: {
                  cout << "Spain" << endl;
                  break;
             }
     case 4: {
                  cout << "China" << endl;
                  break;
             }
     default: cout << "Select from valid set of options";
}
```

Hope this helps.